# Black image when editing through PHP

Tags: php

I found a couple of tutorials to edit image in PHP. However it is showing a black image. I couldn't understand what's the problem here.

```
<?php
  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://iamsaurav.xyz/images/avatar.jpg');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'http://iamsaurav.xyz/images/oswald.ttf';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "This is a sunset!";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

Comment: That link points to the cropping of image. But here I'm trying to add a text to image

Answer (score 0):

If you use the full path to both the image and the font it appears to work fine ~ obviously the paths used here are pertinent to my system so you would need to edit appropriately. The most likely problem is that PHP is looking in the wrong directory for the image.... if the text does not appear then that path is also most likely wrong.

```
<?php
  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  /* use absolute path */
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('C:/Temp2/src.jpg');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'c:/wwwroot/inc/fonts/AMAZON.ttf';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "This is a sunset!";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

Comment: I've used full url, still black image

Comment: Can you update the question to show the actual code you are using now?

Comment: According to the manual regarding `imagecreatefromjpeg` it states `A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename. .....`

For me I found trying that URL failed but the image, when saved locally, worked fine with the code I used... Try using the absolute path rather than a url!! Incidentally there is a typo on your homepage "amatuer" should be "amateur"